# Error while compiling in matlab

Tags: matlab-compiler

I got the following error while running

> source.vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1,'YUY2_320x240');
>
> Undefined function or variable 'videoinput'.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Please post some some code, so others can try and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matlab installation is missing "Image Acquisition toolbox".Install it and run the code again